# Can I use window.setFlags to hide the status bar in API 16 and above

Tags: android

I want to display an image gallery in full screen mode (allowing the user to swipe).

According to this page:

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

For API 16 and above, I should use decorView.setSystemUiVisibility. However, as soon as I touch the screen the status bar returns and I have to touch the screen again to swipe (immersive mode is only available in API 19).

Testing with my Galaxy S4, the code meant for API 15 does what I want:

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Is it okay to use the older code on a device with a newer API level?

Comment: If unsure you could check current version in runtime (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) and provide two versions of code.

Comment: Thanks, I would do that, but I'd really like to know is if I can use the older technique with newer API levels

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe that old method should work on latest Android because it's not marked as deprecated.

Comment: That's what I thought!